# How to remove M line breaks to Normal line breaks in Shellscript in a CSV file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, carriage-return

I have a CSV file file1.csv

```
Name age Id address country
X     12  3  aaa     Italy
Y     13  5  xxx      uk
...
```

I am having text file file2.txt too.

```
 Id 
3
4
5
...
```

I was actually display `Id` and `country`.
Using this two files and display Id and country
I tried this code

```
#!/bin/bash
CSV_FILE_PATH ="root/file1.csv"
Id_txt= 'file2.txt'

for Id in Id_txt
do
LINE $(grep ${Id},$CSV_FILE_PATH})
echo $LINE|awk -F ',''{print $3 "/t" $5}'
done
```

I am getting output of

```
"3","italy" ^M "4","Uk" ^M "5"....
```

Comment: you'll have to convert the file format to unix. Open the CSV file in vim and enter `set fileformat=unix` (and then save with `:wq`). There are other ways to achieve the same

Comment: This is a large CSV file and is there any other way to convert the file.please help

Comment: look at [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Comment: I didn't get the output

Comment: To solve your real  project, read up about the *nix's `join` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dos2unix $INPUT` command doesn't work then you can also use

- `tr -d '\r' < $INPUT > $OUTPUT`
- Or for inplace editing you can use `sed -i 's/\r$//g' $INPUT`